# Dynamically update “firebase-messaging-sw.js” in Angular 11

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have implemented Firebase push notifications in Angular 11 successfully.

Initially, I integrated everything and experienced no issues. However, I encountered a requirement where I needed to have a dynamic Firebase configuration to support different instances such as development and production. I am seeking guidance on how to achieve this dynamic configuration.

I am expecting to load env file in service worker file and don't want to add any hard coded configs.

Comment: You can add a manual build step or script that replaces certain strings, pretty much like workbox uses `self.__WB_MANIFEST`

Comment: @UmbQbify Thanks for sharing the solution. I am not used workbox can you please help me if any implementation available for self.__WB_MANIFEST

Comment: Nothing specific to workbox. I am talking about string replcament, like env variables. like in vite- https://v2.vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files